# \label{} adds space on line break. How do I prevent it?

Tags: spacing, cross-referencing

The following code gives the output below:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition:}[chapter]
\begin{document}
\begin{definition} Some Definition~\\
The defintion
\end{definition}
%
\begin{definition} Some Definition~\\ \label{def:2} % label added
The defintion
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see in the second version of the definition with \label{}, the new line is indented. I assume \label{} is adding a space. How do I stop it?

Comment: Place `\label` just after `\begin{definition}`.

Comment: label is not adding space you have added a space token before and after it. Aso Why have you `~` before `\\ ` ?????

Comment: The space goes away if you use `\label{..}%`, without a space between `\label{..}` and `%`.

Comment: @egreg: That was quick and easy. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle:  I see the error of my ways now. I have been using ~ to allow line breaks at the start of environments like: \begin{example}~\\  \begin{itemize} blah, blah, \end{itemize} \end{example} to avoid "no line to break" compile error. Your question made me realize that adding text after the start of the environment creates a line and the ~ is not necessary. I guess I just got in the habit of putting it in.

Comment: it is always wrong to use`~` before `\\ `

Comment: it is logically wrong and practically it forces a space so prevents the text using the full line. `example` should be defined to have  a break if needed, you should not need `\\ ` and if one-off use does need it `\mbox{}\\ `  is much better than `~\\ `

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. I didn't explain myself well. Some time ago I wanted an itemized list to start after Example. I tried \begin{example}  \begin{itemize} but that resulted in the first 'item' being on the same line as the word Example. I tried \begin{example} \\ but got a compile error - no line to break. I posted that issue here and was offered \begin{example}~\\ \begin{itemize}. It worked. I don't want a permanent change to the definition of example. I don't understand why \mbox{} \\ is much better but I believe you and will use it instead.

Comment: `\mbox{}` is zero width, `~` is a full width space. This _might_ not be visible, but it can affect the typesetting in various ways.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

`\label` checks for space before and after and ensures you do not get a double space but allows one space. You have added two space tokens, the one after `\\`  is ignored but the one after `\label` is a normal space.  The usual position is directly after `\begin{definition}` which is in vertical mode where space is ignored.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition:}[chapter]
\begin{document}
\begin{definition} Some Definition\\
The defintion
\end{definition}
%
\begin{definition} Some Definition\\ \label{def:2} % label added
The defintion
\end{definition}
%
\begin{definition} Some Definition\\\label{def:3} % label added
The defintion
\end{definition}
%
\begin{definition} Some Definition\\ \label{def:4}% label added
The defintion
\end{definition}
%
\begin{definition} Some Definition\\\label{def:5}% label added
The defintion
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```